# Can't access model object data outside the alamofire request scope while populating api data on badoo/Chatto chat text

Tags: ios, json, swift, chat, alamofire

Previously I successfully access model objects anywhere in the class but while populating data on badoo/chatto text view I am stuck.
I am integrating chat message api into badoo chat view

Basically, the issue is alamofire response is not getting outside of the scope.

Did I try with compilation handler but no luck? Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance .

Here is code snippet :

```
import Foundation
import Chatto
import ChattoAdditions
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class DemoChatMessageFactory {
    public static var chats = [ChatModel]()

    class func makeMessage(_ uid:String) -> DemoTextMessageModel{
        print("uid makeMessage : \(uid)")
        return self.makeMessageData(uid, isIncoming:false)
    }

    class func makeMessageData(_ uid: String,isIncoming:Bool) -> DemoTextMessageModel {
        if isIncoming == true{
            return self.makeTextFinalMessage(uid, isIncoming:isIncoming)
        } else {
            return self.makeTextFinalMessage(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming)
        }
    }

    public class func makeTextMessage(_ uid: String, isIncoming: Bool,text:String) -> DemoTextMessageModel {
        let messageModel = self.makeMessageModel(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming,
                                                 type: TextMessageModel<MessageModel>.chatItemType)
        let textMessageModel = DemoTextMessageModel(messageModel:messageModel,
                                                    text: text)
        return textMessageModel
    }

    public class func makeTextFinalMessage(_ uid: String, isIncoming: Bool) -> DemoTextMessageModel {
        var text = String()
        var uidInt  = Int(uid)

        print("string uid 121 \(uid)")
        print("print is Incomming data or not 1: \(isIncoming)")
        print("uid count :\(uid.count)")
        let urlString = "[My message Api]"

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get).validate().responseJSON {
            (response) -> Void in
            if let value = response.data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: value)
                    if let dictionnary = json.dictionaryObject {
                        if let messageArray = dictionnary["message"] as?[[String: Any]] {
                            self.chats.removeAll()
                            for arr in messageArray {
                                self.chats.append(ChatModel(ChatListJSON: arr))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("cannot convert to Json")
                }
            }

            print("print int 122 : \(uidInt!)")
            print("Chat List Id DemoChatMessageFactory \(self.chats[uidInt!].chatId)")
            print("chat message: \(String(describing: uidInt!)) th \(self.chats[uidInt!].chatMessage)")
            self.textData = "\(self.chats[uidInt!].chatMessage)"

            self.makeTextMessage(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming, text:self.textData) //Here I am bale to pass textData but ouside the Alamofire block can't access
        }

        //Here getting empty values
        print("uid makeTextFinalMessage \(uid)")
        print("in coming makeTextFinalMessage \(isIncoming)")
        print("text makeTextFinalMessage \(text)")

        //chat count also getting zero count
        print("chat count final text\(chats.count)")

        print("print chat count : \(self.chats.count)")

        return self.makeTextMessage(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming, text:self.textData)
    }
}
```

Test for completion handler

```
public var res: Any = ""
func getAllChatData(completionhandler:@escaping ([String: Any]?) -> ()){
    let URL = "my api"
    Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
        response in
        if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
            completionhandler(json, nil)
        }
        else if let error = response.result.error as Error? {
            completionhandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

and call using like below inside the function

```
DemoChatMessageFactory.getAllChatData {
    (result) in
    res = result
    print("response (res)")
}
```

please suggest me the proper way to alamofire with compilation handler

Comment: Do you mean **completion handler** with _compilation handler_ ? Please show your code using completion handler if you say you did try.

Comment: public var res: Any = ""

func getAllChatData(completionhandler:@escaping ([String: Any]?) -> ()){
        let URL = "my api"
        Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
            response in
            if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                completionhandler(json, nil)
            }
            else if let error = response.result.error as Error? {
                completionhandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: and call using like below inside the function 

    DemoChatMessageFactory.getAllChatData{
            
            
            (result)  in
            res = result
            print("response \(res)")
            
        }


please suggest me proper way to alamofire with compilation handler

Comment: You should better add the code at the bottom of your question. You can **edit** your own question and edited questions are put in the higher position in the Active list view. And above all, cleanly formatted code is far easier to read, than code in comments.

Comment: @OOPer thanks for response and suggestion I added code in main question

Comment: You'd better give your code a better formatting.  Anyway, can you get the output from your `print("response (res)")`?

Comment: @OOPer inside the makeTextFinalMessage I call this function and I got response

Comment: Seems it's become the limit of adding comments. Anyway you need to use the result only in the completion handler. If you are calling it inside the `makeTextFinalMessage`, it needs to have a completion handler, and your `makeMessageData`, `makeMessage`, all such things need to use completion handlers.

Comment: @OOPer Okk. Thank you so much ...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of converting all methods using the result of asynchronous call. As I have never used `Chatto` and you are not showing all the types in your code, so you may need to modify many parts of my code, but I believe you can see what you need to do with this code.

```
import Foundation
import Chatto
import ChattoAdditions
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class DemoChatMessageFactory {
    public static var chats = [ChatModel]()

    class func requestMessage(_ uid:String,
                           completion: @escaping (DemoTextMessageModel?, Error?)->Void) {
        print("uid makeMessage : \(uid)")
        self.requestMessageData(uid, isIncoming: false) { (model, error) in
            completion(model, error)
        }
    }

    class func requestMessageData(_ uid: String, isIncoming: Bool,
                               completion: @escaping (DemoTextMessageModel?, Error?)->Void) {
        if isIncoming {
            //...put any code needed when isIncoming is true
            self.requestTextFinalMessage(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming) { model in
                completion(model, error)
            }
        } else {
            //...put any code needed when isIncoming is false
            self.requestTextFinalMessage(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming) { model in
                completion(model, error)
            }
        }
    }

    public class func makeTextMessage(_ uid: String, isIncoming: Bool, text: String) -> DemoTextMessageModel {
        let messageModel = self.makeMessageModel(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming,
                                                 type: TextMessageModel<MessageModel>.chatItemType)
        let textMessageModel = DemoTextMessageModel(messageModel:messageModel,
                                                    text: text)
        return textMessageModel
    }

    public class func requestTextFinalMessage(_ uid: String, isIncoming: Bool,
                                           completion: @escaping (DemoTextMessageModel?, Error?)->Void) {
        var text = String()
        var uidInt  = Int(uid)

        print("string uid 121 \(uid)")
        print("print is Incomming data or not 1: \(isIncoming)")
        print("uid count :\(uid.count)")
        let urlString = "[My message Api]"

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get).validate().responseJSON {
            (response) -> Void in
            if let value = response.data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: value)
                    if let dictionnary = json.dictionaryObject {
                        if let messageArray = dictionnary["message"] as?[[String: Any]] {
                            self.chats.removeAll()
                            for arr in messageArray {
                                self.chats.append(ChatModel(ChatListJSON: arr))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    print("print int 122 : \(uidInt!)")
                    print("Chat List Id DemoChatMessageFactory \(self.chats[uidInt!].chatId)")
                    print("chat message: \(String(describing: uidInt!)) th \(self.chats[uidInt!].chatMessage)")
                    self.textData = "\(self.chats[uidInt!].chatMessage)"

                    completion(self.makeTextMessage(uid, isIncoming: isIncoming, text: self.textData), nil)
                } catch {
                    print("cannot convert to Json")
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            } else {
                //better generate an error case result, and call completion.
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed some method names from `make...` to `request...` to show  clarify they are asynchronous methods.

And the usage, if you intend to use your original code as:

```
let model = DemoChatMessageFactory.makeMessage(uid)
//Do some UI updates using `model`...
```

You may need to use asynchronous methods like:

```
DemoChatMessageFactory.requestMessage(uid) { (model, error) in
    if let model = model {
        //Do some UI updates using `model`...
    } else {
        //Do something for the error...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I resolved this issue. Badoo pod restrict to access outside values. I initialized model object  inside the Badoo classes